# How do i convert uploaded csv into json object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('myngCsv', [ngcsv]);
app.controller('ngcsvCtrl', function($scope,$csv) {

    $scope.csv ={
        content: null;
        header: true,
        headerVisible: true,
        separator: ',',
        separatorVisible: true,
        result: null,
        encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
        encodingVisible: true,
        accept: ".csv"
    };

});
```

This is what tried.
indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function to convert CSV to JSON and pass your CSV object to it. All you need to do is to save the first row of CSV as headers (You can identify them by comma) and you can identify new entry by newline character `\n`
Go through the function I have written below.

```
function csvToJSON(csv, callback) {
            var lines = csv.split("\n");
            var result = [];
            var headers = lines[0].split(",");
            for (var i = 1; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
                var obj = {};
                var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
                for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                    obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
                }
                result.push(obj);
            }
            if (callback && (typeof callback === 'function')) {
                return callback(result);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'll try.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Papaparse](http://papaparse.com/) looks very easy and elegant to use

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'll try

Answer (score 0):

Create fileReader directive:

```
<input type="file" data-file-reader-directive="fileContent" accept=".csv" />
```

Directive to get csv data from the file:

```
app.directive('fileReaderDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            fileReaderDirective: "=",
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $(element).on('change', function(changeEvent) {
                var files = changeEvent.target.files;
                if (files.length) {
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    r.onload = function(e) {
                        var contents = e.target.result;
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.fileReaderDirective = contents;
                        });
                    };
                    r.readAsText(files[0]);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Create a factory to convert csv data to json data

```
app.factory('readFileData', function() {
    return {
        processData: function(csv_data) {
            var record = csv_data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            var headers = record[0].split(',');
            var lines = [];
            var json = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {
                var data = record[i].split(',');
                if (data.length == headers.length) {
                    var tarr = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                        tarr.push(data[j]);
                    }
                    lines.push(tarr);
                }
            }

            for (var k = 0; k < lines.length; ++k){
              json[k] = lines[k];
            }
            return json;
        }
    };
});
```

check out the working example : https://plnkr.co/edit/ml29G85knZpWWNdG8TeT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'll try